# Как проверить заполнена ли капча перед отправкой формы? Yandex SmartCaptcha

Tags: jquery

```
Как сделать так чтобы форма не отправлялась, если капча не заполнена выдать предупреждающий текст
```

```js
<script src="https://captcha-api.yandex.ru/captcha.js" defer></script>
```

```html
<div 
  style="height: 100px"
  id="captcha-container"
  class="smart-captcha"
  data-sitekey="key"
></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".form").on('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault(); 

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST", 
         url: "send.php",
         data: new FormData(this),
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         success: function (data) {
            console.log(send);
         },
         error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
         }
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#TestForm").validate({
        ignore: ":hidden:not([name='smart-token'])",
        rules: {
            AccountNumber: "required",
            'smart-token': "required",
        },
        messages: {
            AccountNumber: "* Поле обязательно для заполнения",
            'smart-token': "* Вы должны выполнить антиспам проверку"
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element[0].parentNode);
            $(error).css("display", "block");
        }
    });
```